# How to convert a UIView to a multi-page PDF in swift?

Tags: swift, pdf, uiview, multipage

I have an app, written in Swift and want to export an entire `UIView` as a PDF. I found the code below does this well, but only produces a single-paged, cropped PDF. The exportable `UIView` contains a tableview which is dynamic, so I need to calculate the number of pages depending on the length of the `UIView` (which contains a scrollView for this purpose). Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks!

```
func createPDFFromView(aView: UIView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName fileName: String)
{
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

    guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    aView.layer.renderInContext(pdfContext)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    if let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first {
        let documentsFileName = documentDirectories + "/" + fileName
        debugPrint(documentsFileName)
        pdfData.writeToFile(documentsFileName, atomically: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: did get any solution for this question? if yes please give update.

Comment: @RajJoshi just check PDFGenerator [link](https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/PDFGenerator). It works for me, also they have a demo of how to use it.